# iOS UIImageView Memory Management

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a .png image in an Images.xcassets folder and load it into a UIImageView with the following line of code:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image3"))
```

Suppose, for example, that this image has dimensions 85x85 and the "imageView" has dimensions 50x50. Is there a way to load a scaled-down version of "image3.png" into memory to make the application more memory-efficient?

If this is not possible, are there other ways to make images more memory-efficient? My application uses about 100MB of memory when running on an iPhone 6, and I believe that most of this memory usage is from the images I'm displaying. I feel like that's a very large amount of memory to be using just to display images.

Comment: "and I believe that most of this memory usage" No need to guess. Use Instruments. It will tell you exactly what's going on.

Comment: You could resize the larger image to the size you need. It temporarily will use more memory but the larger image does not have to be kept around.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? Is there a function that does it or something?